# Button Corner to round button (Xcode,Swift)

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, rounded-corners

```
    VStack {
        
            Button("Access") {
                
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Color.orange)
            .padding(.top)
            .accessibilitySortPriority(1)
            .accessibilityAddTraits([.isButton, .isLink])
    Spacer()
        }
```

---

[image]

### How the button is (1)

[image]

How the button is suppose to be (2) - rounded

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/cornerradius(_:antialiased:) ?

Comment: VStack {
            
                Button("Access →") {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .accessibilitySortPriority(1)
                .accessibilityAddTraits([.isButton, .isLink])
                .cornerRadius(80.0)
                .accessibilityElement(children: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.contain/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)